# Load a navigation property value using entity framework core without going through DB context

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

TL;DR: what's the most concise method to load a single navigation property on an entity?

Suppose I already have an instance entity `Foo` with a child `Child`. Instance of `Foo` I have has `ChildId` set but `Child` was not loaded, i.e. `foo.ChildId == 1234` but `foo.Child == null`.

I want to get `Child` if it is missing. I know I can do:

```
if (foo.Child is null) {
    foo.Child = _dbContext.Foos.Include(f => f.Child).Single(f => f.Id == foo.Id).Child;
}
```

but I am looking for a lazy way (pun!) to load it on-demand (I don't want to load all properties on-demand, however, just the one I want to load explicitly), something like:

```
var child = _dbContext.EnsureLoaded(da, e => e.Child);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) in the docs? If `Child` is null, it means Lazy Loading wasn't enabled and the `Child` property isn't `virtual`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [Explicit Loading of Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/explicit)

```cs
_dbContext.Entry(foo).Reference(f => f.Child).Load();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) is already available. There are two options:

- using proxy objects generated by EF Core to automagically load related entities or
- use the `ILazyLoader` service with POCOs to load related entities when requested

**Proxies**

To use proxies, the DbContext has to be configured first :

```
.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

After that, any properties that need to be lazy loaded have to be made `virtual` :

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

At runtime EF will return proxy objects that inherit from the entity classes and overload the lazy properties to load the related object when first requested.

**ILazyLoader service**

Another option, that doesn't require inheritance, is to use POCOs and the `ILazyLoader` service to load the entities when needed :

```
public class Blog
{
    private ICollection<Post> _posts;

    public Blog()
    {
    }

    private Blog(ILazyLoader lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    private ILazyLoader LazyLoader { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _posts);
        set => _posts = value;
    }
}
```

This adds a dependency on the `ILazyLoader` interface itself, which in turn adds a dependency to EF Core in domain or business models.

This can be avoided by injecting the loader as a *lambda*, along with some convention magic :

```
public class Blog
{
    private ICollection<Post> _posts;

    public Blog()
    {
    }

    private Blog(Action<object, string> lazyLoader)
    {
        LazyLoader = lazyLoader;
    }

    private Action<object, string> LazyLoader { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts
    {
        get => LazyLoader.Load(this, ref _posts);
        set => _posts = value;
    }
}
```

This is used in combination with an extension method that actually calls the loader using the property's name and sets its backing field :

```
public static class PocoLoadingExtensions
{
    public static TRelated Load<TRelated>(
        this Action<object, string> loader,
        object entity,
        ref TRelated navigationField,
        [CallerMemberName] string navigationName = null)
        where TRelated : class
    {
        loader?.Invoke(entity, navigationName);

        return navigationField;
    }
}
```

As the docs warn:

> The constructor parameter for the lazy-loading delegate must be called "lazyLoader". Configuration to use a different name than this is planned for a future release.

Comment: Thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos, I am aware of lazy loading (I might have mentioned that in the question), the reason I don't want props to be loaded automatically is because of the serialization and mapping. Which is why I was looking for a method to load data explicitly. But your answer I will be able to apply in other situations in the future, I'm sure.